# Merging 2 models into 1 model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I don't know exactly the term of my problem, maybe thats the reason why I can not find such relevant issues in here.

Say, I have these models.

```
public abstract class Member
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public int  MemberType { get; set; } //1 if person; 2 if business
   //public string MemberName { get; set; } 
}

public class Person : Member
{
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string FirstName{ get; set; }
}

public class Business : Member
{
   public string BusinessName { get; set; }
   public string TaxNo { get; set; }
}
```

Right now, I do not have a problem on accessing those models using fluent API.

Now, what I want to achieve is to add a property on my Member class which is MemberName, which will be derived from LastName and FirstName property of Person class if MemberType is 1 and BusinessName of Business class if MemberTYpe = 2.

Is there an easy way to achieve this kind of thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a bit of `abstract` magic.

On `Member` have this:

```
public abstract string MemberName { get; }
```

Then on `Person` you override as:

```
public override string MemberName
{
   get{ return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
}
```

on `Business` you override as such:

```
public override string MemberName
{
   get{ return BusinessName; }
}
```

Now, any instanceof any class which inherits `Member`, when calling the `MemberName` property will return the right representation. This is all basic inheritance/OOP/Polymorphism whatever you want to call it.

Comment: +1 - this keeps Member closed to change and keeps the logic in the specialisations. It is cleaner than my suggestion too.